# Importing Dotplot from R to Adobe Illustrator causes dot shapes to change

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, adobe-illustrator

Using ggplot, I have created a dotplot with round dots. I use ggsave to export it as a .pdf, and it opens fine on Sumatra Reader, Foxit Reader and Chrome.

However, once I open the .pdf using Adobe Illustrator for some touch ups, all of the round dots turn into rectangular dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can share your code, it might help. However, I faced absolutely no problem while viewing a dotplot in Illustrator. Used the following to generate the dotplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_dotplot()
```

In the Plots viewer, I saved it as a pdf and the opened it in Illustrator (CC 2015).[image]

Comment: Dhiraj I tried what you did, exporting via plots on RStudio instead of using ggsave. It seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks!